# Problems with Password Fields

Tags: javascript, fonts, passwords, password-protection

So I've got a password field, with the value set to "Password." I've got some very simple javascript that sets the value to '' onfocus. I want the password to be blocked out, replaced with dots, as is usual. The problem is, if I make the field a password field, the original value, "Password," appears as dots. Is there any simple way to make the original value "Password" and the rest, after onfocus, dots? Or would I have to change the font after onfocus as well to a custom font that's only dots?

Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>SuM BUTtonsS DOe</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="buttons.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Please enter the password.</p>
    <form>
        <input id="password" type="textbox" value="Password" onfocus="if (this.value=='Password') this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value='Password';"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need JavaScript for that. Use the [placeholder](https://developers.whatwg.org/common-input-element-attributes.html#attr-input-placeholder) attribute. Worst case, it's not supported and the field will just be empty. (It's [widely supported now](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder), though).

```html
<input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
```

Comment: Just wondering, is there any way to change the color/transparency of the placeholder text?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css

Answer (score 0):

It is will be more simple, just use type='password':

```
<input id="password" type="password" value="Password" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use placeholder as Toofy said in his answer.

If you want to do it in the way you started, change the type attribute to switch between text and password :

```
<input id="password" type="textbox" value="Password" onfocus="if (this.value=='Password') { this.value='';this.setAttribute('type','password')};" onblur="if (this.value=='') { this.value='Password';this.setAttribute('type','text'); }"/>
```

Fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/1y7Levr4/